# How to fix the problem Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body

Tags: reactjs, forms, routes, react-hooks, components

I've been working in a new application, I've made two different routers this because in one I only gonna work when the user is logout(login screen) and the others when the user is authenticated the problem is that everytime my apps tries to find a route of that second router the above error appears.

I made the proofs in my primary router (login routes) if I put all the routes there I don't have any problem to access.

this is my first router

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/" component={DashboardRoutes} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

as you can see when the url comes only with '/' the second router is called.

```
export const DashboardRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mt-2">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/empleados" component={Empleados} />
          <Route exact path="/clientes" component={Clientes} />
          <Route exact path="/visitas" component={Visitas} />
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

the error says that is a problem with my hook in the login component so I'll add it only to confirm if the problem could be there, although as I said, I made the proofs with all the routes in the first router and everything works. Here is the code of the login app:
even if I just have this on the login component the error appears

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
        username: '',
        pass:''
});
```

update:

[this is the error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bPZV.png)

Comment: So where is React saying there's an issue with a React hook? It seems like you are saying React says it's in the `Login` component but that you don't believe and think the issue is elsewhere? Does navigating to "/login" have the error? Is this the same issue as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596798/how-to-fix-error-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body)?

Comment: Hi Drew and thanks for answer me, this error doesn't appear when I'm in login, I've followed some answer of the questions with the same issue,  I have updated my react and react dom, y ran the command npm link to remove duplicated dependencies and nothing. Yes Is the same issue as my previous question but more explained

Comment: If the error doesn't appear when you are on the "/login" path then please update your question to include the relevant code using a React hook. I guess it is one of the components rendered by `DashboardRoutes` component.

Comment: the problem here is, yesterday I moved to "/login" to keep working with this as you can see in the above code if I login with the correct credentials, I should be moved to "/home" path but when I moved to there the error appeared again mentioning that the problem was with the hook of login, so that Is why I mentioned that the problem could be with the component dashboardroutes because, any route I tried to go that Is declared in this component shoots the above error the only link that hasn't this problem Is login

Comment: Right, I suspected it was your `Home` component since that is the route and component that is rendered by the dashboard if not specifically navigating to one of the other routes. Can you include `Home` component code in your question? You can also help eliminate code that is ok by removing all the other routes so you are rendering ***only*** the dashboard and home page (or try for each component one at a time to see which is causing the error).

Comment: After a while looking for what could be the problem I realized that everything was okay with dashboard routes, the problem was with the component over those routes, the navbar, there I was calling wrongly the login in a tag link, I wrote like to={Login} instead of to="/login", thanks for all your help